# Csv file upload into database using shell script shows error

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, csv

I'm uploading a csv file using the script

```
values ()
{
cat "$@" | \
while IFS=, read  -r a b c d;do 

printf ' %s\n' "$c"

done | \
paste -sd,-
}
```

Inserting data using

```
printf 'INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`)VALUES(%s)\n'     "$(values $_csv_files)" | \
  mysql -u"$_db_user" -p"$_db_password" "$_db"
```

I get the following error

```
 ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'c' in 'field list'
```

I've been stuck here for the past few hours,Please help me.

Here is the Input(csv file):

```
    a,b,c,d
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/07/08,2014/07/08,"Cash Withdrawal by Cheque-173320--TT1421957901"
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/07/08,2014/07/08,"Cheque Paid-173261--TT1421951241"
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/07/08,2014/07/08,"Cheque Paid-173298--TT1421951226"
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/06/08,2014/06/08,"Cash Withdrawal by Cheque-173319--TT1421858465"
```

Comment: Output of your function with your csv file: `2014/07/08, 2014/07/08- 2014/07/08, 2014/06/08`

Comment: @Cyrus but I keep getting the error,why is that?

Comment: I don't know. Your question lacks the upload part of your script.

Comment: @anubhava expected output? well I need to convert the csv data into a table format so that I can put the values under the column **c** to database.

Comment: Yes that is what expected output will be. Can you show those insert sql that you expect from above input.

Comment: I need to insert the values  2014/07/08, 2014/07/08- 2014/07/08, 2014/06/08 into 'manufacture_name' column in database.

Comment: @anubhava I'm really new to shell scripting,so please help me in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use awk on your csv file like this to generate sql queries:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{printf "INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES(\047%s\047)\n",
          $3}' file.csv
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/07/08')
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/07/08')
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/07/08')
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/06/08')
```

---

**EDIT:** To do that without awk you can do:

```
while IFS=, read -r _ _ c _; do
   [[ $((++i)) != "1" ]] && 
      printf 'INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES (\047%s\047)\n' "$c"
done < file.csv
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/07/08')
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/07/08')
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/07/08')
INSERT INTO `manufacturemap`(`manufacture_name`) VALUES ('2014/06/08')
```

Comment: I know,but I'm supposed to do this with a shell script.

Comment: Yes,it does help,But its also inserting in the header name.How to exclude that?